# php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App doesn't generate new fields

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony-4.3

I updated this entity adding some fields.

Now I'd like to regenerate getters and setters but whe I execute `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App` I have no results; my entites are listet but it says "no change". I'v tried event with --overwrite option.

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProfessionalRepository")
*/
class Professional
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $actiu;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Especialitat")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $especialitat;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getNom(): ?string
{
    return $this->nom;
}

public function setNom(string $nom): self
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

public function getActiu(): ?bool
{
    return $this->actiu;
}

public function setActiu(bool $actiu): self
{
    $this->actiu = $actiu;

    return $this;
}
}
```

I'm using symfony 4.3.8
In previous versions I did it executring 'php bin/console doctrine:genetrate:entities App', I'm not sure if I can use this command in symfony 4, anyway it neither doesn't work.

I'm don't know what else to try...

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it clearing the cache after each change.

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```